# Linq to SQL Query with fk

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq-to-sql

I try to realize this query from T-SQL in Linq to SQL:

```
Select * from RPG r
join RPGPlayer e on r.RPGID = e.RPGID
join [User] i on e.UserID = i.UserID
where i.Username like '%Dunkel%'
```

The result is correct for 2 Rows on SQL-Query itself.

I try this:

```
rpgList.Where(y => y.RPGPlayers == y.RPGPlayers.Where(e => e.User.Username.Contains(player))).ToList();
```

(rpgList is a list of the complete table loaded before)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not entirely sure regarding the question, but the following is my attempt to represent the SQL join statement in LINQ …

```
from r in RPG  
join e in RPGPlayer on r.RPGID equals e.RPGID  
join i in User on e.UserID equals i.UserID  
where i.Username.Contains("Dunkel")
```